# Validation in post method

Tags: c#

Clase modelo

```
 public class SDN
        {
            [Key]
            public int Id { get; set; }
            public int Codigo {get; set;}
            public string nit { get; set; }
            public string nombre { get; set; }
            public string telefono1 { get; set; }
            public string telefono2 { get; set; }
            public string direccion { get; set; }
            public string email { get; set; }
            public string codciudad { get; set; }
            public string codtipo { get; set; }
    }
```

Clase DTO

```
public class SdnDTO
            {
        
                public int Id { get; set; }
                public int Code { get; set; }
                [Required(ErrorMessage = "The field SDN Nit is required ")]
                public string nit { get; set; }
                [Required(ErrorMessage = "The field SDN Nombre is required ")]
                public string nombre { get; set; }
                public string telefono1 { get; set; }
                public string telefono2 { get; set; }
                public string direccion { get; set; }
                public string email { get; set; }
                public string codciudad { get; set; }
                public string codtipo { get; set; }
        
        }
```

//Repository

```
public async Task<TEntity> Insert(TEntity entity)
        {
            try
            {
                centralContext.Set<TEntity>().Add(entity);
                await centralContext.SaveChangesAsync();
                return entity;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }         
        }
```

// Service

```
public async Task<TEntity> Insert(TEntity entity)
    {
        return await genericRepository.Insert(entity);
    }
```

I have this method in my controller

```
  /// <summary>
        /// Metodo Insert
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="sdnDTO"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Post(SdnDTO sdnDTO)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
                return BadRequest(ModelState);
            try
            {
                var sdn = mapper.Map<SDN>(sdnDTO);
                sdn = await sdnService.Insert(sdn);
                return Ok(sdn);
            }
            catch (Exception ex) { return InternalServerError(ex); }
        }
```

Before inserting I need to validate that the Code exists
How can I validate that before inserting this record there are no matches?
or how could I put that code to be unique and not touch the database, only in code

Comment: Can you show your sdnService.Insert method? The logic to do what you are asking will likely be added to that method, not the controller. Then you can bubble the result back to the controller for handling and return to the client rather than returning OK for every result without an exception.

Comment: Thanks I already added it

Comment: generally, when checking for duplicates, you must do a database call to check for that.  Add a query that matches on all fields and if you get a record back, it's a duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

In your service before you do your insert you could call your repository to see if any results are returned matching the code. If they are you can return a bad result back to your service, which then passes it back to the controller. You could define a Result object that encapsulates that logic with a bool for success/failure, and an error message string that states why it failed.